# Linear approximation of the given equation with python3

Tags: python, linear-regression, data-science-model

I was given a set of raw datum and have to model it by means of some machine learning techniques. After some research, I decided to do with the method of linear approximation.

---

#### Description of the equation.

[image]

- z - depth (meters)
- T(z) - temperature at the depth z
- T(zᵢ) - temperature at the depth zᵢ
- T₀ - temperature at the surface (It is constant and known)
- K - coefficient of geothermal gradient (How the temperature changes with respect to the depth)
- Mᵢ - flow rate of the liquid at the depth zᵢ

  ---

As it is shown from the equation we can find the temperature of the liquid in the any depth of the well bore.

I have list of **depths**, **temperature** and the **flow rate** of the liquid. I have to model an equation according to these datum by means of python3 and find `K` and `c`. Currently I use matplotlib library for such type of calculations.

---